# Why do we need to set rpc address in hdfs-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, rpc

In hdfs-site.xml, we set 
    **dfs.namenode.rpc-address** parameter. I would like to understand the significance of setting that parameter. I know what rpc address means but why does hdfs need us to set that parameter?

Comment: An address is an address. Do you know what **RPC** means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It handles all the client request.

Quoting [from Apache doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)

> RPC address that handles all clients requests. In the case of
>   HA/Federation where multiple namenodes exist, the name service id is
>   added to the name e.g. dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ns1
>   dfs.namenode.rpc-address.EXAMPLENAMESERVICE The value of this property
>   will take the form of nn-host1:rpc-port.